# How to use Triangle inequality to find the projection onto unit ball?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

The projection onto the unit ball 
$$C:=\mathbb{B}(0,1)=\{x:||x||\leq1\}$$ is given by $$P_{C}(x)=\frac{x}{max\{||x||,1\}}, \quad\forall x\in X$$ where $X$ is Hilbert space. Now I can understand this but I want to use triangle inequality to show that $\frac{x}{||x||}$ is the closest point to the $\mathbb{B}(0,1)$ when $||x||\geq1$ (mabe multivalued) unless the norm is strictly convex. I am not able to built this argument using triangle inequality so if anyone can help me with this or can do this using a triangle inequality I will be very thankful to him.

Comment: Triangle inequality will not help much. You have to use Cauchy-Schwarz. Btw norms in Hilbert space are always strictly convex (even uniformly convex).

Comment: if the unit ball is in Banach space then we need to use triangle inequality to prove that, I think! Also, can you show me how using Cauchy-Schwarz? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

Suppose that there exist points $x$ and $y$ in a normed space $X$ such that $\|x\|\ge 1$, $y\in C$ and 
$$\|x-y\|<\|x-P_C(x)\|.$$ Then Triangle inequality implies $$\|x\|\le \|x-y\|+\|y\|<\|x-P_C(x)\|+1=\|x-P_C(x)\|+\|P_C(x)\|
=\|x\|,$$ a contradiction.